# Rails - Association Alias resolves to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure if this is namespace related, trying to sort it out:

I have this working example:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    include Sortable
    include Filterable

    attr_filter :id, :email, :name, :category_id

    belongs_to :category, class_name: "OrganizationCategory"
end
```

Which, If I call for example on rails console:

```
o = Organization.first
o.category
```

I get the expected behaviour, which is, replacing the need to call `o.organization_category` by calling `o.category` and getting the association.

However, Tried with a different model `Team`

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    include Sortable
    include Filterable

    attr_filter :id, :name, :sex

    belongs_to :sport, class_name: "AthleticSport"

end
```

If I use `belongs_to :athletic_sport` and call `t.athletic_sport` works fine, But when I add `class_name` to `belongs_to` and try to call `team.sport`, I get `nil`.

Any idea, on what is causing this? Is it because, `OrganizationCategory` has the word `Organization` in it? while `Team` differs from `Athletics`?

Is there a workaround this?

Comment: What is your foreign_key field called? It needs to be `sport_id` if you don't specify it via `foreign_key: ...`?

Comment: On point @ChristopherOezbek, I specified on `belongs_to` the correct foreign key name and it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Best to put that in an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Needed to specify `foreign key` on `belongs_to`

```
belongs_to :sport, class_name: "AthleticSport", foreign_key: :athletic_sport_id
```